# I got compilation error during one ocaml function call

Tags: ocaml

Thanks for your attention. I encountered an ocaml funcion calling problem. Here it is.

This is the function definition. Suppose these are defined in pp.ml.

```
    let ast_exp_to_string = pp2string (fun p -> p#ast_exp ~prec:0)

    let ast_exp_to_string_in_varctx ctx = pp2string_with_pp ctx 
    (fun p-> p#ast_exp ~prec:0)


    let pp2string f v =
      let strpp = new pp ft in
      pp2string_with_pp strpp f v

    let pp2string_with_pp pp f v =
      Format.pp_open_box ft 0;
      f pp v;
      Format.pp_print_flush ft ();
      let s = Buffer.contents buf in
      Buffer.reset buf;
      s

    let make_varctx () =
      new pp ft
```

I can successfully call **ast_exp_to_string** like this **Pp.ast_exp_to_string e**

but when I call **ast_exp_to_string_in_varctx** with

```
    let varctx = Pp.make_varctx;;

    Pp.ast_exp_to_string_in_varctx varctx e
```

I got compilation error like the following:

```
Error: This expression has type unit -> Pp.pp
       but an expression was expected of type
         < ast_exp : prec:int -> 'a -> 'b; .. >
```

Could you please help me take a look? What could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to apply an argument to a function `varctxt`. It accepts one argument of type `unit`. So the correct code would be:

```
let varctx = Pp.make_varctx ();;
Pp.ast_exp_to_string_in_varctx varctx e
```

Comment: Hi, I added and tried again. Still got the same error. Error: This expression has type Pp.pp but an expression was expected of type
         < ast_exp : prec:int -> 'a -> 'b; .. >

Comment: yep, and what do you want?

Comment: I'd like to call the function Pp.ast_exp_to_string_in_varctx. I am not very familiar with ocaml. So could you please help me? As I understand, Pp.ast_exp_to_string_in_varctx expects two arguments. First is the ctx, second is an ast exp. So why does the compile still complain? Thanks.

Comment: First of all the error is not the same. Second, it is not possible to guess, what's going on. I don't know what is `Pp.pp`, what is `pp` and whether they are of the same type. You didn't provide enough information.

Comment: Hi Ivan. As you might figure out, this is part of the code in BAP version 0.8. `Pp.pp` is the class `pp` defined in pp.ml.

Comment: I have no experience with bap 0.8, but at least now I know where to look. I will see, if I can figure out what is going on. Also I would suggest you to use newer version of BAP 0.9.9. It is a complete rewrite that is much more user friendly.

Comment: ok, this is just an error in legacy bap. Presumably, you can fix it, by adding an explicit type annotation in the definition of `ast_exp_to_string_in_varctx`. You need to constrain type of `p` argument like this: `( p : pp)` .
And again, bap legacy is not supported anymore. You should really consider to switch to a new bap. It is much more user friendly, with lots of documentation and support, like chats, issue trackers etc.

Comment: Hi Ivan. Thanks so much for your help. I know version 0.8 is no longer maintained. But I need to use the symbolic execution part. I may switch to newer version later. Thanks a lot!